# WebViewController. Exception has occurred. ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Missing scheme in uri: null)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterwebviewplugin

I am trying to pass data from previous page(news_card.dart) to another page(news_details.dart) to view in WebViewController. but for loadRequest(Uri.parse(widget.link)) I have received an error "Exception has occurred.
ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Missing scheme in uri: null)"

Here is my code for news_card.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:lumi_news/page/news/news_details.dart';

class NewsCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final CollectionReference collectionReference;

  NewsCard({super.key, required this.collectionReference});

  PageController? _controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: collectionReference.snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("error");
          }

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = snapshot.data;
            List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = querySnapshot.docs;

            List<Map> items = documents
                .map((e) => {
                      'id': e.id,
                      'newsTitle': e['newsTitle'],
                      'publisherName': e['publisherName'],
                      'imageUrl': e['imageUrl'],
                      'publisherImageUrl': e['publisherImageUrl'],
                      'publisherRectangleUrl': e['publisherRectangleUrl'],
                      'updated': e['updated'],
                      'link"': e['link'],
                    })
                .toList();

            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Map thisItem = items[index];
                return Container(
                  //padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                  height: 150,
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => NewsDetails(
                                    link: '${thisItem['link']}',
                                    image: '${thisItem['publisherImageUrl']}',
                                    title: '${thisItem['publisherName']}',
                                  )));
                    },
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 3,
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            width: 110,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                              color: Colors.white,
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                image: NetworkImage('${thisItem['imageUrl']}'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 10,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '${thisItem['publisherName']}',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '${thisItem['newsTitle']}',
                                    maxLines: 3,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 30,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '${thisItem['updated']}',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here news_detail.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class NewsDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  final String link;
  final String title;
  final String image;

  NewsDetails({required this.link, required this.title, required this.image});

  @override
  State<NewsDetails> createState() => _NewsDetailsState(link, title, image);
}

class _NewsDetailsState extends State<NewsDetails> {
  WebViewController? _controller;

  final String link;
  final String title;
  final String image;

  _NewsDetailsState(this.link, this.image, this.title);

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            // Update loading bar.
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {},
          onPageFinished: (String url) {},
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(widget.link));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        title: Container(
          width: double.maxFinite,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Image.network(
                  widget.image,
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  height: 32,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                child: Text(
                  widget.title,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: WebViewWidget(controller: _controller!),
    );
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks for any help !